# Want change the active state on my one page section navbar using Flat UI bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I Want my navbar to change active state of my link when the page is scrolled at the section associated with that link and when I click that link to go to that section. the navbar goes to section on the page not to another page. I am using bootstrap for this website.

This is the Html

```
<header id="navbar">
    <div class="row" id="navbar-1">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="navbar-2">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse myActlink" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section2">Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section4">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

I tried using this jquery code but it changes the active class but I can't go to the any of the section when I click it

```
$('.myActlink li').click(function(e) {
    $('.myActlink li.active').removeClass('active');
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
        $this.addClass('active');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a `#idname` in `href` attribute it looks for the id in the page and scrolls down/up to that part so that the top of that *element* is the top of the window. In your case you might be missing the `id="section1" in your HTML. I am not sure because I can just see header part of your HTML.

On clicking:

```
<a href="#section1"></a>
```

The page will scroll the page to:

```
<div id="section1"></div>
```

**Extra:** For a smooth transition scroll effect you can use [Chris Coyier](http://chriscoyier.net/)'s brilliant smooth scrolling [plugin](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/).